# Confirmation Dialog in PHP, according to data found in mysql db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

- I am developing some database with a php/css interface...
- I want to know how can I pop up a Confirmation Dialog in my PHP code, yes/no type, dependending in the consequences of my code. Basicly, if theres something on database or not, tell the user and ask the user how he want to proceed.

Here's part of the code:

```
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$existID = $recResult["uniqueID"];
if($existID=="") { 
    ->POPUP HERE CONFIRMATION DIALOGUE "It doesnt exists, add new?"
} else {
    ->POPUP HERE CONFIRMATION DIALOGUE it already exists, wright over old data?
}
```

Comment: You are probably looking to have this code output a call to a javascript function that handles popups or a standard confirmation type dialog box. However, that process will be asynchronous after the page loads; because you'll have to wait for the user's response before proceeding. So, you can't really have that logic in PHP on the server side.

If you want to handle their response with a dialog on the same page, your logic for handling that will have to be in javascript, which might then make an ajax call back to a PHP script to handle the server-side/database processing and return a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PHP is running on the server side, there is no direct way to display some dialog to the user.

You need to generate a piece of user interface using HTML / CSS / Javascript that enables your user to execute the desired steps.

A very simple example could be

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$existID = $recResult["uniqueID"];
if($existID=="") { ?>
    <a href="your_app.php?create=1">
        It doesn't exist, click to add new
    </a> 
<?php
} else { ?>
    <a href="your_app.php?id<?php echo $existID; ?>=&overwrite=1">
        It exists, click to overwrite
    </a> 
<?php
}
```

This will render a link in the HTML result, which your user can choose to open.